# WebRTC remote audio recording solution

Tags: javascript, php, audio, webrtc, video-recording

I am working on **video-conferencing** with `WebRTC` (javascript/php). I want to record whole screen i.e. all videos in single video and store it on server. I am able to record single video at a time but not all videos at a time(whole screen). Can I achieve it?

And one big issue is **Remote Audio recording**! Is there any solution to record remote audio??

I have taken the code from [here](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RTCMultiConnection/RecordRTC-and-RTCMultiConnection.html#38EWVRS7-KOTJ4I).

Comment: Asking for 3rd party resources i.e. plugins is considered off-topic. I won't flag your question though because other than that bit I believe it is a legit question and you have done some effort already.

Comment: @NSNoob : thanks for honest response. Yes I had search things but failed. Can you suggest any solution if u have please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think `php` is going to make a difference here, I can see only two ways.

**The Easy Way:**

Use an MCU for recording( even as an alternative for mesh network for conferences). You can try [Kurento](https://www.kurento.org/), [Licode](http://lynckia.com/licode/index.html) or [Intel CS](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/webrtc/#).

**The Hard Way**:

if firefox browser: use `MediaRecorder` api to record each remote stream, send them to server and merge them together( may be with ffmpeg) and provide a link to user to see/download...

if chrome browser: you can record through each remote video stream canvas( what happens in `RecordRTC` internally), simultaneously request the remote peers to record their own audio on their side, upload them all to the server and provide link... yeah, good luck with syncing them all.

Comment: I think I should go with 1st way..because i cant request remote peers for audio so I will not have WAV. Or is there any way that I can record my own desktop screen?

Comment: Desktop stream is just another media stream, makes no difference to the recorder, but to obtain the stream, you ll probably need to add plugins to the browser...